# A remark about $\rho$ and $G$ being simply connected

Tags: algebraic-groups, root-systems

Let $G$ be a reductive complex algebraic group, $H \subset G$ a Cartan subgroup and $R^+$ a set of positive roots, and $X_+(H)$ the set of dominant weights. Let us also assume that $G$ is simply connected.

I read in [these notes](https://kumar.math.unc.edu/notes/kumar_notes_03.pdf) "Since $G$ is simply connected, $\rho := \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in R^+} \alpha \in X_+(H)$".

For me, simply connected means $\pi_1(G,e) = \{1\}$. How to deduce the claim ?

It seems to me that it's always true. Indeed, $s_i$ preserves all positive roots but $\alpha_i$ so $s_i \cdot \rho = \rho - \alpha_i$ so it follows that $\langle \rho, \alpha_i^{\vee}\rangle =1$. In fact this equality is explicitly stated a bit after the definition of $\rho$. So how it is related to $G$ being simply connected or not ?

Comment: Indeed, there is no reason why it should be simply connected. But there also does not seem to be any claim following it, unless $\rho$ has been defined in some other way some other place.

Comment: Ohh, nevermind, I mised that it claimed that $\rho$ was dominant.

Comment: The issue here is that while it is true that the $\rho$ defined is always dominant, it need not actually be a weight, since you need to divide by $2$, which might break things (for an example, consider a suitable $PSL_n$)

Comment: Where is this from, btw? It would make more sense if it said "if" instead of "since", so it might be a typo. Or maybe the setup was specialized further before getting to that point.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Ah I understand, so it's in $X_+ \otimes \Bbb Q$ but maybe not in $X_+$ ? Anyway I added the reference. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : also sorry, I think Kumar probably assumed that $G$ is simply connected. But even with this assumption I don't understand the connection between$\pi_1 = 1$ and the fact that $\rho$ is a weight.

Comment: $G$ being simply connected is equivalent to the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of the coroots being all of the cocharacters of the maximal torus. This implies that there is a dual $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the space of characters, and in that case the $\rho$ defined coincides with the sum of the elements of this dual basis (these are the fundamental weights).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Thank you, and sorry that I formulated my question in a misleading way before.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that some authors (for example Springer in _Linear algebraic groups_) actually take the _definition_ of "simply connected semi-simple algebraic group" to mean that the coroots span the cocharacter lattice.

Comment: @Joppy Yes, that is also how Jantzen does it. I am not sure if I ever actually saw a proof connecting the concepts.